# Issue With Spreadsheets

Tags: json, google-sheets, spreadsheet

Actually I Am Converting The Data Present In Google Sheets To JSON Format ,

( ' https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/_google_sheet_id/od6/public/values?alt=json ' )

And I Am Using It For A Long Time , But Recently When I Opened The JSON Converted Link , I Faced A Issue

```
Sorry, unable to open the file at this time.

Please check the address and try again.
```

I Thought Only I Faced This Issue But I Had Another Link With Same Issue ,

I Think There's A Problem From Server's End

If Not Let Me Know The Reason Or

**Any Other Alternatives To Convert *Google Sheets To JSON* Format**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using an endpoint corresponding to [Google Sheets v3 API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/v3), which shut down on August 2, 2021. Please take a look at the migration guide to v4 provided below.

I'm not sure what exactly you want to accomplish, but if you want to [retrieve data](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/migration#retrieve_row_data) from a specific sheet in v4, you could do something like this:

```
https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/{SPREADSHEET_ID}/values/{SHEET_NAME}?alt=json
```

#### Reference:

- [Migrate to the Google Sheets API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/migration)

Comment: Thanks It Really Helped Me !!

Comment: @daksh You're welcome. Please consider accepting this answer, if it was useful to you https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work.